# Using an internal pull-down resistor on a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pulldown

I am using an STM32 microcontroller.

If I configure a pin as input with a pull-down resistor for use with a button, do I also need to put a resistor between the input pin and VDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you put the button between the input pin and V<sub>DD</sub>. Putting a resistor will simply create a way for electricity to flow from V<sub>DD</sub> to V<sub>SS</sub>, using up power needlessly.